# Error en repositorio mongo metodo find() en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con DDD y arquitectura hexagonal con typescript. Tengo un repositorio para la entidad de cursos que tiene dos métodos:

El primer método recopila un documento pasándole el id.
El segundo método realiza una búsqueda de todos los documentos.
El problema es que en el método searchAll la constante "documents" (Que deberia devolver el array de documentos) no contienen los documentos de la colección. Devuelve datos de mongo en RAW pero NO el array de documentos, dejo el código del repositorio aquí:

```js
import { Nullable } from '../../../../Shared/domain/Nullable';
import { MongoRepository } from '../../../../Shared/infrastructure/persistence/mongo/MongoRepository';
import { Course } from '../../domain/Course';
import { CourseRepository } from '../../domain/CourseRepository';
import {CourseId} from '../../../Shared/domain/Courses/CourseId';

export class MongoCourseRepository extends MongoRepository<any> implements CourseRepository {

  public async search(id: CourseId): Promise<Nullable<Course>> {
    const collection = await this.collection();
    const document = await collection.findOne({ _id: id.value });
    return document ? Course.fromPrimitives({ ...document, id: id.value }) : null;
  }

  public async searchAll(): Promise<Nullable<Array<Course>>> {
    const collection = await this.collection();
    const documents = await collection.find({});
    return documents;
  }

  protected moduleName(): string {
    return 'courses';
  }
}
```

Comment: No creo que sea posible obtener un array de su base de datos a menos que uses algo como `$objectToArray` que no recomiendo. Puedes hacer un array despues como: `return [documents]`? Y no necesitas `{}` en `collection.find()`

Comment: El problema es que el .find() no me esta retornando ningun resultado sino "datos de la peticion a mongo"

Comment: Puedes hacer esto:
`collection.find({}).exec(function (err, miLista) { if (err) { console.log(err); } console.log('Mi lista: ', miLista); return miLista;});` ?

Comment: No te devuelve *datos de la petición*, te devuelve un [*cursor*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/). Lo que tu necesitas es usar el método [`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) de dicho cursor para que obtengas la lista de documentos: `const documents = await collection.find({}).toArray();`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: si me funciono con solo el .toArray()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como te digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398547/error-en-repositorio-mongo-metodo-find-en-typescript#comment713017_398547), el problema está en que el método [`find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) del Driver de MongoDB para NodeJS, realmente devuelve un [`cursor`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html), (en MongoDB: [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)), que es un tipo de objeto iterable especial para trabajar con colecciones de datos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, podrías hacer uso del método [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#toArray) de dicho *cursor*, de tal forma de obtener todos y cada uno de los documentos de la colección consultada. Por ejemplo:

```
const documents = await collection.find({}).toArray();
```

Otra forma de obtener los datos es iterando dicho *cursor*, y en cada iteración obtener el documento al que apunta el *cursor*. Para ello podemos hacer uso de los métodos [`hasNext()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#hasNext) y [`next()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#next) del cursor. Por ejemplo:

```js
const documents = []; // lista para almacenar los documentos
const documentsCursor = await collection.find({}); // <- cursor
while(await documentsCursor.hasNext()) {
  let document = await documentsCursor.next();
  documents.push(document);
}
console.log(documents); // <- contiene la lista de documentos
```

Claramente el método `toArray()` es mucho más claro y directo que el código anterior.